# [JS]Return to index page

Tags: javascript

How can I return to the registration page from the oauth authentication?
I put the url of the app(as &redirect_uri=) but when the user accept the authentication, the script fails:

```
Error: Access to 'app://6cb90889-d3dd-4ca7-8bab-ea11831b922d/reg.html#access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx' from script denied
```

It should close the browser and return to the app! Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

redirection of url are taken care by server. Server has to understand the redirect_uri= attribute and need to redirect it.

In case of J2EE.
it will be done as

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        String contextPath= "http://www.java2s.com";
    response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(contextPath + "/maps"));
  }
```

Let me know if your trying someting different.

Regards,
Chandra.